# Reporting services database was NATIVE, now it's UNKNOWN

Tags: sql-server, migration, ssrs, configuration

After migrating a database from Sql Server 2012 to Sql Server 2014, we found a little problem.

It was told me that the reporting server was not used, so I just installed the SQL Server 2014 and migrate the database. Everything was ok.

But now, I noticed that users are having problems with reporting services ( yes, they use Reports ).

Long story short, Why is the ReportServer database `unknown`, if it was `Native`?

[image]

I could change to make some tests, but now I can't set it back, because it's unknown. Why is the database not native anymore?

Is there something to do to make it back to Native?

---

---

EDIT 1:

What I tried to to is:
1) backup up `reportserver` and `reportserverTEMPDB` Database

2)Restore it on the new SQL Servrer 2014 instance

3)Points the "database" to this database as shown below:

[image]

After moving it, now it is native ( but only on the new instance ), but when I try to access the URL, it shows me this error:

> **The report server installation is not initialized(rsReportServerNotActivated)**

but As shown here, it is activated:

[image]

in [This question here,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554088/reporting-services-2008-the-report-server-installation-is-not-initialized) he says that he made this step-by-step:

> **Reporting Services Configuration Manager - Encryption Keys - Delete
>   - Encrypted Content - Delete**

I really don't know if a should do this. What am I going to delete? It will delete some data of the database  ( not the reportServer database, the database that we are using to get data )

Comment: Still Waiting...